# c++ how to read and store values from a sentence

Tags: c++

So there is an input file that contains something like

```
name1 arrival 20 service 20
name2 arrival 22 service 11
name3 arrival 23 service 40
```

and I'm trying to store name1, name2, name3 in string name,
arrivals (20, 22, 23) in int arrival, and service (20, 11 ,40) in int service.
I know I would have to use while loop and getline, but Im not really sure what to do. Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to show **what you've tried** or this is off-topic here. Since you know it involves a loop, start there, sketch that in, work through it step by step.

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in a loop is a good start. Then continue with experimenting with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) which works just like any other input stream (like e.g. `std::cin`) to extract the fields you want. Then consider reading about *structures* (or classes of course) to group the values. And lastly how about a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store the structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threw together a quick example program for you. Basically, you'll want to use stringstream to store into whatever data structure you need. There may be special solutions based on what architecture you're working with, but hopefully this will get you started.

```
  std::string str = "name1 arrival 20 service 20\nname2 arrival 22 service 11\nname3 arrival 23 service 40";
  std::stringstream iss(str);

  // Create temporary variable to store each line
  std::string line;

  // Data to hold each item
  std::string name[3];
  int arrival[3];
  int service[3];
  std::string trash; // For throwing out data

  // Read stream line by line
  int index = 0;
  while (getline(iss, line))
  {
    // Parse the line
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    // Read each attribute into the appropriate data structure
    lineStream >> name[index];
    lineStream >> trash;
    lineStream >> arrival[index];
    lineStream >> trash;
    lineStream >> service[index];

    // Increment index
    ++index;
  }

  // Print out the results
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Index[" << i << "]: " << name[i]
              << ", " << arrival[i] << ", " << service[i]
              << std::endl;
  }
```